# Executing typescript code using ts-node gives "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error

Tags: node.js, typescript, compilation, tsconfig, ts-node

I am trying to run `apollo-server` and the code I have written is in `TypeScript`.

My code folder contains a `tsconfig.json` which looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "server"
  ]
}
```

The command I am running is below:

```sh
$ npx ts-node ./server/index.ts
```

If I remove the tsconfig.json (which of course I can't do), the command above works fine. I am not sure which configuration is actually causing the problem.

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: @Pablo For now I have temporarily removed the module option which seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

the setting you are searching is `"module": "commonjs"`. As ts-node is executing your code in the nodejs environment you have to use its module system. If you need your config as default for your project you can create a second tsconfig `tsconfig.node.json` and target it with `ts-node --project <tsconfig.json>`

`tsconfig.node.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
  },
}
```

Comment: I tried changing module option to ``commonjs``. It didn't work. I have es6 style imports in the code. It throws an error for that.

Comment: I will give this second approach of providing a separate ``tsconfig.json`` file a try.